# GPAW get_wigner_seitz_ldos Error

Tags: gpaw

I was trying to use the get_wigner_seitz_ldos function of GPAW for a toy system (calculated using Gamma point only), and I'm getting the below error.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

```
calc.get_wigner_seitz_ldos(a=0,spin=0, npts=201, width=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/storage/home/nvs5847/.conda/envs/newest_gpaw/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpaw/calculator.py", line 1703, in get_wigner_seitz_ldos
    energies, weights = raw_wignerseitz_LDOS(self, a, spin)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/storage/home/nvs5847/.conda/envs/newest_gpaw/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpaw/utilities/dos.py", line 305, in raw_wignerseitz_LDOS
    gd.integrate(abs(np.where(atom_index == a, psit_G, 0.0))**2) +
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in where

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (15,15,40) (602,) ()
```

Here is the corresponding input file

```
from ase import io
from ase.io import write
from gpaw import GPAW, PW
from gpaw import Mixer, MixerSum, MixerDif
from ase.optimize import QuasiNewton
from ase.constraints import StrainFilter, UnitCellFilter


cell=io.read('POSCAR')
cell.center()

#resultfile = open('energies_kpts.txt', 'w')

encut=600

calc_pw = GPAW(txt='C_PW%sx%sx%s.txt' % (1,1,1),xc='LDA',kpts={'size': (1, 1, 1), 'gamma': True},mode=PW(encut))
cell.set_calculator(calc_pw)
#optimizing cell
sf = UnitCellFilter(cell)
opt = QuasiNewton(sf,trajectory='%sx%sx%s_bfgs_ls.traj' % (1,1,1), restart='%sx%sx%s_bfgs_ls.pckl' % (1,1,1))
opt.run(0.05,steps=10)

calc_pw.write('gammapt_only_contcar.gpw', mode='all')


from gpaw import GPAW, FermiDirac
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from gpaw import GPAW

calc = GPAW('gammapt_only_contcar.gpw')

atom_index=0
e_a, ldos_a = calc.get_wigner_seitz_ldos(a=atom_index,spin=0, npts=201, width=None) #if width is None: width = 0.1 by default
plt.plot(e_a - e_f, ldos_a)
plt.axis([-15, 10, None, 4])
plt.title(f'Atom # {atom_index}')
plt.ylabel('LDOS')
```

And the POSCAR that is read in the beginning is

```
generated by phonopy
   1.0
     2.4461088393633634    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
    -1.2230544196816819    2.1183923953103418    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    6.6480114768766381
C
   4
Direct
  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.7500000000000000
  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.2500000000000000
  0.6666666666666666  0.3333333333333333  0.7500000000000000
  0.3333333333333333  0.6666666666666666  0.2500000000000000
```

Comment: Please supply an input file

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, please see here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qESkHh53KQrcPTK2NajrPKgT0oMRbj_rGxxYLPgFrz4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @NataLya please see [this](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5) and edit your question accordingly. Please let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Sorry about the google drive link, I wasn't aware of the rule. Let's try this again. @TristanMaxson, please see the input file in my edited question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Nata, hopefully that is enough to help get your question answered!

Comment: I don't know myself but I posted the question to the GPAW Element chat.  Hopefully someone knows there and can get you an answer.